# how to concatenate the coordinates of two sublist as pair list?

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following sublist format:

```
x = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]

y = [[11, 22, 33, 44], [55, 66, 77, 88], [99,100, 111, 122]...]
```

Above is a sublist containing the information of the "x" and "y" coordinates (the length can be changed accordingly).

Now I like take two sets and make pair of coordinates as following:

```
x_y = [[(1,11),(2,22),(3,33),(4,44)],[(5,55),(6,66),(7,77),(8,88)],[(9,99),(10,100),(11,111),(12,122)...]
```

any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `zip` twice:

```
x_y = [zip(a, b) for a, b in zip(x, y)]

print(x_y)
```

Output:

```
[[(1, 11), (2, 22), (3, 33), (4, 44)], [(5, 55), (6, 66), (7, 77), (8, 88)], [(9, 99), (10, 100), (11, 111), (12, 122)]]
```

Comment: @MrGeek Yes, using the `zip(a, b)` is correct because it requires a list of tuples as the OP requires, but in case of `zip(x, y)` it can be `itertools.izip(x, y)` instead because it is meant to be iterated over. But I removed my comment because it was too minor a point.